# MATCH AGAINST script is not working with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I try to set this class in my Symfony2 project :
http://xlab.pl/en/full-text-searching/ (Match against part)

This class is supposed to allow me to use the Match against with doctrine like this :

```
$searchResult =      $em->createQueryBuilder('uvaluo_user')
                                ->addSelect("MATCH_AGAINST (uvaluo_user.firstname, uvaluo_user.lastname, :name 'IN NATURAL MODE') as score")
                                ->add('where', 'MATCH_AGAINST (uvaluo_user.firstname, uvaluo_user.lastname, :name) > 0.8')
                                ->setParameter('name', $name)
                                ->getQuery()
                                ->getResult();
```

As they said in the website I put that in my config.yml of my app :

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
      string_functions:
        match_against: Uvaluo\UserBundle\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainstFunction
```

And I have the class MatchAgainstFunction like this

```
<?

namespace Uvaluo\UserBundle\Extension\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

/**
 * @example by https://gist.github.com/1234419 Jérémy Hubert 
 * "MATCH_AGAINST" "(" {StateFieldPathExpression ","}* InParameter {Literal}? ")"
 */
class MatchAgainstFunction extends FunctionNode {
//Content that I got in the website
}
```

And finally when I try my code I get that following error :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 107 near 'MATCH_AGAINST': Error: Class 'MATCH_AGAINST' is not defined.
>   500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
>   1 linked Exception: QueryException »

Do you know what can be the reason of that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this article [Extending DQL in Doctrine 2: User-Defined Functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html):

config.yml:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    dql:
      string_functions:
        MATCH: My\Bundle\DQL\MatchAgainstFunction
```

MatchAgainstFunction.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

/**
 * MatchAgainstFunction ::=
 *  "MATCH" "(" StateFieldPathExpression {"," StateFieldPathExpression}* ")" "AGAINST" "("
 *      StringPrimary ["BOOLEAN"] ["EXPAND"] ")"
 */
class MatchAgainstFunction extends FunctionNode {

  /** @var array list of \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\PathExpression */
  protected $pathExp = null;

  /** @var string */
  protected $against = null;

  /** @var boolean */
  protected $booleanMode = false;

  /** @var boolean */
  protected $queryExpansion = false;

  public function parse(Parser $parser) {
    // match
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

    // first Path Expression is mandatory
    $this->pathExp = array();
    $this->pathExp[] = $parser->StateFieldPathExpression();

    // Subsequent Path Expressions are optional
    $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
    while ($lexer->isNextToken(Lexer::T_COMMA)) { 
      $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA); 
      $this->pathExp[] = $parser->StateFieldPathExpression(); 
    }

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);

    // against
    if (strtolower($lexer->lookahead['value']) !== 'against') {
      $parser->syntaxError('against');
    }

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
    $this->against = $parser->StringPrimary();

    if (strtolower($lexer->lookahead['value']) === 'boolean') {
      $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
      $this->booleanMode = true;
    }

    if (strtolower($lexer->lookahead['value']) === 'expand') {
      $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
      $this->queryExpansion = true;
    }

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
  }

  public function getSql(SqlWalker $walker) {
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($this->pathExp as $pathExp) {
      $fields[] = $pathExp->dispatch($walker);
    }

    $against = $walker->walkStringPrimary($this->against)
        . ($this->booleanMode ? ' IN BOOLEAN MODE' : '')
        . ($this->queryExpansion ? ' WITH QUERY EXPANSION' : '');
    
    return sprintf('MATCH (%s) AGAINST (%s)', implode(', ', $fields), $against);
  }
}
```

In your repository:

```
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    
    public function getUsingAgainstMatch() {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb
            ->select('m')
            ->from('MyBundle:MyEntity', 'm')
            ->andWhere('MATCH (m.field) AGAINST (:field) > 1')
            ->setParameter('field', 'value')
        ;
        return $qb;
    }

    //...

}
```

You can find on this [repository](http://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) a lot of Doctrine Extensions.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but I get this now :
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1214 The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: @Picoss The location of dql in your config.yml was incorrect for me. It needed to be within an entity_manager definition

Comment: @Picoss how would I set boolean mode in your repository function example?

Comment: @Picoss also, how would I reuse the score returned by the MATCH e.g. SELECT MATCH(..) AGAINST (..) AS score

Answer (score 1):

you can install doctrineExtensions by requiring`"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions":"^1.0",` in  your composer. then you will have alot of mysql functions as well as **Match** then you can use the match function in where clause in querybuilder or custom queries without any problem.

After installing the bundle you need to go to the config file and add your needed functions

```
doctrine:
   .
   .
   .
    orm:
    .
    .
    .
       dql:
           string_functions:
                MATCH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\MatchAgainst
```