# Symfony2 and Match Against, table InnoDB

Tags: symfony, doctrine, innodb, full-text-search

I had a problem to implement Match Against with symfony2, but I almost solve the problem thanks to stackoverflow :
[MATCH AGAINST script is not working with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534796/match-against-script-is-not-working-with-symfony2)

I did what Picoss said, but now I have another problem :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1214 The used table type doesn't
>   support FULLTEXT indexes

After some search on google I suppose the reason is because of InnoDB table type, but I don't know how to change it in Symfony2 (and I have to search something on a table generated by an entity of fosuserbundle. Second solution can be to upgrade my mysql version (I am actually on the 5.1.66-0 version, but I am not sure if it will solve the problem or not).

Do you have any other ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with Symfony2, you should change your table definition to the MyISAM engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the engine option in the @ORM/Table definition:

For annotions:

```
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity", options={"engine"="MyISAM"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\Bundle\Entity\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 */
class MyEntity
{
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after adding that option, I did "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" and I got Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
Do I have to drop the database and rebuild it ?

Comment: It worked thanks but I had to do this : ALTER TABLE uvaluo_user ADD FULLTEXT(firstname, lastname);
Is there a annotation way with ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with Doctrine:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_table_name", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="escape", columns={"name"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\YourRepository")
 */
class YourEntity extends SomeClass {

}
```